# how to update or delet from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

> I am new to database i just created a simple database .please let me know how to delete a single row from this data base and how to edit a single row from this database :)
>   thanks in advance

```
  void createDatabase(String time, String day,String course,String room,String syl){

       database = openOrCreateDatabase("newDb",MODE_PRIVATE, null);


         sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS examTab (Time VARCHAR ,Day VARCHAR ,Course VARCHAR ,Room VARCHAR ,Syl VARCHAR );"; 
         c = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

        database.execSQL(sql);


    String insertSql = "INSERT INTO examTab VALUES('"+time+"','"+day+"','"+course+"','"+room+"','"+syl+"');";
    database.execSQL(insertSql);


    database.close();


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create, delete, update : SQLiteOpenHelper « Database « Android

```
public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  try {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  Log.w(TAG, oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
      + ", which will destroy all old data");
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
  onCreate(db);
}



public long insertContact(String name, String email) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
  }

  public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
  }

  public Cursor getAllContacts() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
    KEY_EMAIL }, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

  public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
    KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
    null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
      mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
  }

  public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name, String email) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    args.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,null)> 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For DELETE operations** you can see here :
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

In your case this should become :

```
database.delete("examTab", "condition", null);
```

**For UPDATE operations**, you can see the method here:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("COLUMN_1", newValue);
cv.put("COLUMN_2", newValue);
... and so on
database.update("examTab", cv, "condition", null);
```

PS: the whereArgs parameter is usefull if you add "?" as placeholder in condition clause to prevent SQLInjection, but if you dont care about you can put null

Comment: database.delete("examTab", "condition", null);

what is the "condition" here?

Comment: "condition" depends on your need, maybe could be a row ID, or a group of column values to identify one or more row to update.

Example condition: "Day = '1' AND Course = 'English'"

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE examTab WHERE Time = x AND Day=y AND Course =z;
-- update Time for the rows meeting WHERE filter specified
UPDATE examTab
SET Time=x2
WHERE  Time = x AND Day=y AND Course =z;
```